# How to call Java code from Xpand?

Tags: xtend, xpand

I want to call an arbitrary Java method from an Xpand template (e.g. a static method). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a mapping for the Java method in the template. This excellent post explains the process in detail http://pettergraff.blogspot.de/2009/11/how-to-write-extension-in-xtend-for.html

Example:

**CalledJavaCode.java**

```
package template;

public class CalledJavaCode {
    public static String evaluate(Object o) {
        return "some evaluation";
    }
}
```

**Template.xpt**

```
//Xtend mapping for Java in template file
String eval(Object this) : JAVA
    template.CalledJavaCode.evaluate(java.lang.Object);

// Template.xpt usage of mapping
«FOREACH attribute AS a»
    «eval(a)»
«ENDFOREACH»
```